# The specified locale is not supported on this operating system. [ LCID = -1 ]

Tags: mysql, sql, sdf, compact-database

It's my first post here, so sorry for any mistakes I make.

I get this error when I try to open a compact database with a program called **Edusal**, I tried also to open it with *SDF viewers* but they give me the same error, can someone help me?

> The specified locale is not supported on this operating system. [ LCID
>   = -1 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the database, add `LCID=1030;` to your connection string, this property is a creation time property and has no effect when the database is already created.